# how to add the multiple pipe, comma etc after few spaces in string php

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone please help me regarding this issue, i tried alot regexp and substr too but im unable to figure it out.
My requirement is to add | sign in string after 1, 28, 48, 62 and so on! im converting a text file into psv format for our crm, can anybody help me regarding this?
Regards

```
$final = preg_replace("/^(.{0})/", "$1|", $line[0]);
```

this code is matching only one position per string, i want to replace to 6-10 specific columns, i tried this too but not working

```
$final = preg_replace("/^(.{0}{28}{48})/", "$1| $2| $3|", $line[0]);
```

but my solution in this expression if it works
one more example
input:

```
$string = "80293066640226135465        NRIC                011064608711  HAZRY BIN ABDULLAH                                                                                                                                    0138258856                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     LOT 7083,LORONG 6B1 JLN MATANG                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                TAMAN MATANG JAYA                                                                                                       93050,KUCHING,SAR                                           93050               SAR                                     ABO TAYANGAN HEBAT FOR VALUE PACK,ABO TAYANGAN HEBAT HD,AOTG + CATCH UPMALAY                         URB4929                1                   2015090404/09/2015      04/11/2015      138.0000                                          BASIC FAMILY HD PACKAGE,HD SERVICES FOR VALUE PACK,RECORDING (XTV) FOR
```

";
desired output:

```
80293066|640226135465|NRIC|011064608711|HAZRY BIN ABDULLAH||0138258856||||$ $ $LOT 7083,LORONG 6B1 JLN MATANG$|TAMAN MATANG JAYA $93050$,KUCHING,SAR $SAR $||ABO TAYANGAN HEBAT FOR VALUE PACK,ABO TAYANGAN HEBAT HD,AOTG + CATCH UP|MALAY|URB4929||1|20150904|04/09/2015|04/11/2015|138.0000||BASIC FAMILY HD PACKAGE,HD SERVICES FOR VALUE PACK,RECORDING (XTV) FOR|||
```

so some fields will have | sign and some will have $.

Comment: What do you mean by "so on" ?

Comment: Do you want to replace `,` with `|` ? using regex ? please specify an expected output for your sample input.

Comment: No, i want to replace some specific column number with | this. 
i.e ive a text file and its containing these records
973293273 john joe downtown london uk 6499273 
now i want to add | this with after first column started at  |973293273 and next | want to add with |john joe and so on... the pattern is based on column numbers like first pipe sign will be added at position 1 and than pipe sign will be added at 12 position and so on...

Comment: Please provide a sample input string and exected output.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give several examples showing both input and desired output.

Comment: Explanatory as a closed book

Comment: `{n}` is not a position inside the string. It is a number of occurrences of the preceding subpattern in the input string. `.{0}` means *match any non-newline symbol 0 times*.

Comment: $output = "|".substr($input,0,9)."|".substr($input,10,24)."|"; etc if i understood correct? You just want to get x letters, add a | , pass 1 letter, get y letters etc?

Comment: @Elentriel yes bro you are taking me right!! you got the point.

Comment: How do you understand that in `john joe downtown london uk`, `john joe` is separate field and `downtown london uk` is a separate field ?

Comment: that would also be my second question. is, for every row of your data, the name for example the same length?

Comment: well i want to add pipe sign at 0 length and than on 13 length and than on 28 length, and than 48 n 63 ..... continue, i can understand that fields are separated because length is fixed, i can make a script in which ill fix the length of address field starting, fix the length of name field, I'll not separate this list on empty spaces base, I'll separate this list on length based

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following syntax, perhaps there are more simplified way, the number of dots matches the number of characters you need to place the "|" symbol.

```
preg_replace("/^(........)(.........)(...................)/", "|$1|$2|$3", $line[0]);
```

in the vi I use

```
:%s/^\(........\)\(.........\)\(...................\)/|\1|\2|\3/g
```

Comment: im unable to use 11 or more times this expression, any other help?$final = preg_replace("/^(.{0})(.{10})(.{29})(.{49})(.{63})(.{213})(.{233})(.{253})(.{293})(.{401})(.{628})/",
  "$1| $2| $3| $4| $5| $6| $7| $8| $9| $10| $11| ",$line[0]);

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have input like this:

```
973293273    john joe       downtown london uk  6499273
```

and since you have a fixed length file, this pattern can be used:

```
^(.{13})(.{15})(.{20})(.{15})$
```

and replace it with something like:

```
|$1|$2|$3|$4
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bS7hR2/1)

Comment: this one is really good but im unable to add 10 regular expression in one state, $final = preg_replace("/^(.{0})(.{10})(.{29})(.{49})(.{63})(.{213})(.{233})(.{253})(.{293})(.{401})(.{628})/",
  "$1| $2| $3| $4| $5| $6| $7| $8| $9| $10| $11| ",$line[0]);

Comment: you can combine regexes using `|` sign like `regex1|regex2` also, as i wrote `.{13}` it means 13 characters make sure when you write `.{293}` you were expecting 293 characters for this field, you can check for position 28 i didn't write `.{28}` instead  `(.{13})(.{15})`. can we get the whole string so this pattern can be adjusted to match your all 10 expressions ?

Comment: i've more than 30 columns and some column have different starting char like
80293066|640226135465|NRIC|011064608711|HAZRY BIN ABDULLAH||0138258856||||$ $ $LOT 7083,LORONG 6B1 JLN MATANG$|TAMAN MATANG JAYA $93050$,KUCHING,SAR $SAR $||ABO TAYANGAN HEBAT FOR VALUE PACK,ABO TAYANGAN HEBAT HD,AOTG + CATCH UP|MALAY|URB4929||1|20150904|04/09/2015|04/11/2015|138.0000||BASIC FAMILY HD PACKAGE,HD SERVICES FOR VALUE PACK,RECORDING (XTV) FOR|||
this is the output i want, some $ signs and some | signs are mixed

Comment: Which columns do you have $ as a starting characters ? You can adjust this regex to capture all matches (instead of replace in single step with your expected character(s)), then run a loop on all matches and join them as per your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Should every row have fixed size per column (first column 10 characters, second 20 characters etc, notice here the diference between fixed and max, every single column must have the same length exactly

```
function char_replace($input , $replace , $position)
        {
            if(is_array($position))
            {
                $output = $input;
                foreach($position as $character_to_change)
                {
                    $tmp = substr($output , 0 , $character_to_change -1);
                    $tmp .= $replace;
                    $tmp .= substr($output , $character_to_change );
                    $output = $tmp;
                }
                return $output;
            }
            else
            {
                $output = substr($input , 0 , $position -1);
                $output .= $replace;
                $output .= substr($input , $position );
                return $output;
            }
        }
        //example with array
        $string = "12345";
        echo char_replace($string,"|",array(2,4));
            //example
            $string = "abcdef";
            echo char_replace($string,"|",2);
```

this function could help you well. 
do something like this:
$result= char_replace(char_replace($input,"|",48),"|",12); or just run it with a for

EDIT: working with an array for multiple position as well as single int now

Comment: please have a look at example

Comment: can i add replacing characters of my own choice like im adding a positions of my own choice, char_replace($string,"|",array(0,9,30,51,66,217,233,253,293,401,628,1138,1258,1264,1318,1323,1338,1357,1378,1449,1479,1490,1502,1522,1530,1546,1562,1612,1683,1890,1900,1905)); can i use this as > char_replace($string,array("|","|","|","|","|","|","|","$","$","$","#","#","|","|","|","|","|","|","|",), array(0,9,30,51,66,217,233,253,293,401,628,1138,1258,1264,1318,1323,1338,1357,1378,1449,1479,1490,1502,1522,1530,1546,1562,1612,1683,1890,1900,1905));

Comment: more like 
$string = char_replace($string,"|",array(2,4,7,15));
$string = char_replace($string,"$",array(6,8));
Meaning, one call for each char you want replaced , then feeding the output to next call.
didnt plan that far ahead and would kinda break the code to try and include now (for example, what happens if the 2 arrays are of a different length?) I can however make such a function if the above way of reasoning doesn't work for you ~

Comment: thank you so much @Elentriel because of you i solved my problem, what i did is just this: $data = trim(preg_replace("/\s\s+/","$1",char_replace($line,array("|","|","|","|","|","|","|","|","|","|","|","$","$","$","$|","$","$","|","|","|","|","|","|","|","|","|","|","|"),array(8,29,50,65,166,217,238,259,280,301,382,638,1149,1270,1331,1353,1394,1466,1497,1501,1522,1543,1552,1569,1586,1597,1638,1710)))); and change the char_replace function to accept the array of 2nd parameter

Comment: But of course my pleasure :)
If it helped you put this as accepted answer